# Will paper damage my Xbox 360, internally?

Tags: xbox-360

When it first got stuck, the Xbox 360 started making strange noises, and I could not open the disc drive. After a gentle smack, the drive opened, but the piece of paper was gone.

How would I safely remove this piece of paper without causing damage to my Xbox? Alternatively, would there be any potential issues with playing my Xbox with the piece of paper in there?

Comment: What kind of paper, and how big of a piece?